# Where did my car go when I purchased a motorcycle?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I purchased a motorcycle, on GTA5 Online. I have a 6 car garage which had a Zentorno in it. But after I purchased the motorcycle the vehicle disappeared.

I didn’t hit replace or transfer. Where is my car or how can I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

After 2 hours I was able to find my vehicle and get it back.

First I checked the inventory for my personal ok nal vehicles and it showed it was destroyed (I don't know how that happened). I then called mors mutual insurance and then tracked my car and was able to retrieve it, so now it's back in my garage.

Comment: Hi, are you the same user as the one that asked the question?